# UILabel Dynamic Height Extra Margin on Top and Bottom

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

I have a UILabel placed in a view and I've set the number of lines to zero because the text is dynamic. I've pinned the left and right sides of the UILabel to the container and set the vertical spacing between the UILabel and it's neighbors. When I run the application, everything looks good in portrait mode, but when I rotate the device, there is a lot of white space on the top and the bottom of the UILabel. I need to tighten that up but I haven't had any success.

As you can see, things look good in portrait mode.[image: portrait mode]

But not so good in landscape mode.[image: landscape mode]

And here is how my Storyboard looks.[image: storyboard]

I've been doing a lot of reading on StackOverflow over the last few days and I've seen a lot of different answers but none of them seem to work for me. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not certain of the solution immediately, but I can tell you the problem is the label height is remaining the same.  The text in a label is always centered vertically... so the empty space is a result of the label height not being decreased appropriately (since the width is wider, making the words wrap differently).

Comment: Did anybody find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the UIScrollView you have things embedded in is not resizing itself as you're expecting on rotation. The UIScrollView is sticking way down off the bottom of the window, and your UILabel is extending down out of the window as well because your constraints say the label's bottom edge is fixed relative to the bottom edge of the scrollview.